# Using MPI I/O to extract a part of a C structure

Tags: c, struct, io, mpi

I am working on a C MPI code.  It has a structure:

```
typedef struct mystruct_s{
   double interesting_data;
   int boring_data;
   int trivial_data;
}mystruct;
```

Now, each process has an array of these structures, say

```
mystruct my_own_struct[M][N];
```

where M and N are "large", and all of the various process arrays make up one large array of `mystruct`.

Now, I need to output the `interesting_data` values into a single array in a file.  As I have tried to indicate with the variable names, I do not want to output the other parts of the structures.  I want to use MPI I/O to do this.  I could, of course, just establish in each process a double array and copy `interesting_data` into it and take it from there.  But, that makes for a big increase in memory usage, and is not terribly elegant coding.  I'm still learning my way around MPI I/O and MPI derived datatypes.  Is there a way to use them to "extract" `interesting_data` immediately out of the arrays of structures and output it to a large array with MPI I/O?

Comment: MPI is for passing messages. And even iff they would be able to extract a specific field, they had to copy them into an array, too, which is the same overhead you have to do. If you want to avoid that overhead, you have to re-design your data structures.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Is the array stored in a disk file and you want to only read the relevant field out of each file record (doable with MPI IO) or is the already in memory? What would you like to do with `interesting_data`? Send it around or process it locally? Please provide an example.

Comment: @HristoIliev   `insteresting data` is in memory in the running code.  I want to write it all out to a file.  I edited to try to make this clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the interesting data is a single `double` field, then you can simply create a resized version of `MPI_DOUBLE` that has the same extent like the structure:

```
MPI_Datatype newtype;
MPI_Type_create_resized(MPI_DOUBLE, 0L, sizeof(mystruct), &newtype);
MPI_Type_commit(&newtype);
```

Now, when provided with that datatype, MPI will take one `double` value and then skip over the rest of the structure, thus landing at the next `double` value. And so forth.

You can store the data now using e.g.:

```
MPI_File fh;
MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, "interesting_data.dat",
              MPI_MODE_CREATE | MPI_MODE_WRONLY,
              MPI_INFO_NULL, &fh);
MPI_File_set_view(fh, rank * M*N * sizeof(double), // possible integer overflow!!!
                  MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_DOUBLE, "native", MPI_INFO_NULL);
MPI_File_write(fh, &my_own_struct[0][0].interesting_data, M*N, newtype,
               MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
MPI_File_close(&fh);
```

The `MPI_File_set_view` positions the file pointer for each rank and tells MPI to not perform any binary conversion. The `MPI_File_write` call will then write consolidate the `interesting_data` fields and write them as a single chunk at the location specified by the file view. It will work even when `interesting_data` is not the first field of the structure.

If `interesting_data` consists of more than one structure fields, e.g.

```
typedef structure _foo
{
   int couldnt_care_less;
   double interesting_bar;
   int not_interesting;
   int interesting_baz;
   double less_interesting;
} foo;
```

a structure type should be created first:

```
MPI_Datatype stype;
int lens[2] = { 1, 1 };
MPI_Aint disps[2] = { offsetof(foo, interesting_bar), offsetof(foo, interesting_baz) };
MPI_Datatype types[2] = { MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_INT };
MPI_Type_create_struct(2, lens, disps, types, &stype);
// MPI_Type_commit(&stype) is not necessary
```

Now the type has to be resized, exactly like in the simpler example above:

```
MPI_Datatype newtype;
MPI_Aint lb, extent;
MPI_Type_get_extent(stype, &lb, &extent);
MPI_Type_create_resized(stype, lb, sizeof(foo), &newtype);
MPI_Type_commit(&newtype);
```

This procedure makes the new datatype have the same lower bound as `stype`, which will simplify the write call. The trick is to properly set the file view. It requires that yet another structure type be created, consisting of the interesting fields with no spacing between them (unless you'd like to waste disk space by having garbage in the file):

```
MPI_Datatype ftype;
int lens[2] = { 1, 1 };
MPI_Aint disps[2] = { 0, sizeof(double) };
MPI_Datatype types[2] = { MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_INT };
MPI_Type_create_struct(2, lens, disps, types, &ftype);
MPI_Type_commit(&ftype);
```

This datatype is then used to set the file view:

```
// possible integer overflow!!!
MPI_Offset offset = rank * M*N * (sizeof(double) + sizeof(int));
MPI_File_set_view(fh, offset, ftype, ftype, "native", MPI_INFO_NULL);
MPI_File_write(fh, my_own_struct, M*N, newtype, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

This works since `ftype` and `newtype` are congruent -- they consist of the same basic elements (one `double` and one `int`) and in the same sequence.

Comment: Wow!  A real dissertation!  Thanks.  Will certainly give it a shot!

Comment: All this time in the field and I never thought about using RESIZED to extract one specific item out of a struct.  I was worried about compiler padding: my initial thought was to loop over the array of structs and construct an HINDEXED_BLOCK with the value from MPI_ADDRESS